# Authenticity of a narration

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Asalamu Alaikum,

I wanted to ask about the Authenticity of this hadith from Kanzul 'Ummaal [كنز العمال](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/2277_%D9%83%D9%86%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A1%D9%A3/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_635):

> Narrated by Ibn Abbas:
>
> "I (Muhammad) put on her my shirt that she may wear the clothes of heaven, and l lay down (اضطجعت) with her in her coffin (grave) that I may lessen the pressure of the grave. She was the best of Allah's creatures to me after Abu Talib"... The prophet was referring to Fatima , the mother of Ali."

Sorry I didn't find the number or page or original Arabic text.